# Nullpointer exception when invoking EJB

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, nullpointerexception

The following code seems to throw a `NullPointerException` at the `QuestionRepository` class, but I don't managed to fix it. I don't know if I have done anything wrong with the context dependency injection?

Entity

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name=Question.ALL, query="SELECT q FROM Question q")
})
public class Question implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2402027045394206281L;

    public static final String ALL = "Question.all";
```

Repository

```
@Named
public class QuestionRepository {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="SertifikatPU")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public List<Question> all() {
        TypedQuery<Question> query = entityManager.createNamedQuery(Question.ALL, Question.class);
        return query.getResultList();
    }
}
```

EJB

```
@Local(QuestionLocal.class)
@Stateless
public class QuestionServiceBean implements QuestionLocal {

    @Inject
    private QuestionRepository questionRepository;

    @Override
    public List<Question> findAllQuestions() {
        return questionRepository.all();
    }
}
```

Backing bean

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class QuestionIndexBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4228471944163051591L;

    @Inject
    private QuestionLocal questionBean;

    private List<Question> questions;

    public void init() {
        setQuestions(questionBean.findAllQuestions());
    }

    public List<Question> getQuestions() {
        return questions;
    }

    public void setQuestions(List<Question> questions) {
        this.questions = questions;
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
WARNING: A system exception occurred during an invocation on EJB QuestionServiceBean method public java.util.List com.mycompany.application.QuestionServiceBean.findAllQuestions()
javax.ejb.EJBException
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.processSystemException(BaseContainer.java:5193)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.completeNewTx(BaseContainer.java:5091)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4879)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2039)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1990)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:222)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
    at $Proxy208.findAllQuestions(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections$13.work(SecureReflections.java:305)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.run(SecureReflectionAccess.java:54)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.runAsInvocation(SecureReflectionAccess.java:163)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections.invoke(SecureReflections.java:299)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.invoke(EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.java:125)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:62)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:125)
    at com.mycompany.application.org$jboss$weld$bean-SertifikatEJB_jar-SessionBean-QuestionServiceBean_$$_WeldProxy.findAllQuestions(org$jboss$weld$bean-SertifikatEJB_jar-SessionBean-QuestionServiceBean_$$_WeldProxy.java)
    at com.mycompany.web.QuestionIndexBean.init(QuestionIndexBean.java:25)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:234)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:297)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:43)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:56)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.core.DeclarativeSystemEventListener.processEvent(EventHandler.java:128)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent$ComponentSystemEventListenerAdapter.processEvent(UIComponent.java:2508)
    at javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.processListener(SystemEvent.java:106)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.processListeners(ApplicationImpl.java:2129)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.invokeComponentListenersFor(ApplicationImpl.java:2077)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:286)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:244)
    at javax.faces.application.ApplicationWrapper.publishEvent(ApplicationWrapper.java:670)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:108)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1539)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:174)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mycompany.repository.QuestionRepository.all(QuestionRepository.java:17)
    at com.mycompany.application.QuestionServiceBean.findAllQuestions(QuestionServiceBean.java:21)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1052)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1124)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:5366)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:619)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:571)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor109.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:861)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:571)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doAround(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:162)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:144)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor108.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:861)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:370)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:5338)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:5326)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:214)
    ... 61 more
```

Persistence XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="SertifikatPU">
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/sertifikat</jta-data-source>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Project structure:

[image]

Comment: Please add the code of `QuestionRepository`.

Comment: @CodeBrickie - It is already added:)

Comment: Please paste here your `persistence.xml`. Clearly the `entityManager `is `null`

Comment: Cannot see the images. I suppose they show the missing code. Could you please paste the code as text?

Comment: @Baluc - I don't think the `QuestionRepository` need `@Named`. AFAIK, `@Named` is added so the class can be referenced directly from the `facelets` view.

Comment: @Balusc - Every class is injectable with `@Inject`. This is by specification. It doesn't need the `@Named`.

Comment: @BalusC - Yes, correct:)

Comment: I guess it has to be either a managed bean or an ejb. `QuestionRepository` is none of them as far as I see in the code he posted.

Comment: @BalusC - I have written a `DAO` only with simple classes(without `@Named`) and it uses `@PersistenceContext` without problem.

Comment: @Hyperion - Try to make the `QuestionIndexBean` only `@Named` and `@SessionScoped` for the test. Remove the `@ManagedBean` and `@ViewScoped`.

Comment: @Hyperion - Maybe there is a problem that you have an ear `with` three projects. Try to make everything in one project, for the test. I think there can be bug in injecting when there are separate projects.

Comment: @Hyperion - Do you have `beans.xml` in every of your projects?

Comment: Take this to chat, and come back with a conclusion on how to best clean up the question, or start removing prior comments, as the comment stream is getting out of hand and will probably get purged soon.

Comment: @PetarMinchev It works! It is the JPA project that mess it up. When I copied the files to the EJB project and removed it from the assembly  & build path it works.

Comment: @Hyperion - Glad to help:) Maybe there is a bug in the frameworks. I will add this as an answer.

Comment: @PetarMinchev Awesome! Thank you. Strange though, because it should work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to merge the projects in one. Maybe there is a bug in the frameworks when more than one project is used.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is located at your class QuestionRepository.

If I've read it right, this is a simple class, not a server managed class. What does it mean? It means that due that this cause, this piece of code

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName="SertifikatPU")
    private EntityManager entityManager;
```

does nothing because the class is instanced by you, nor by the server, so the persistence context is unknown from the point of view of the class. The consequence is that at this other piece of code

```
public List<Question> all() {
        TypedQuery<Question> query = entityManager.createNamedQuery(Question.ALL, Question.class);
        return query.getResultList();
    }
```

entityManager will be null so it will cause the null pointer exception.

The solution? Declare QuestionRepository  as an EJB too, as example . This way the Persistence Context injection will be automatically done by the server and the entity manager will be initialized at the moment you try to execute the query